# Is there anything in place to sabotage Windows 10 VM guest Blu Ray playback?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, blu-ray

I'd like to play back commercial Blu Ray movies on my Linux computer. I'm not terribly enthused about streaming or ripping from MakeMKV or Dump HD. I just want to play straight off the disc and without a Rube Goldberg configuration. I'd like to know if I could just run a Windows 10 VM for this playback, or if this is a hole Hollywood remembered to plug. Or if there's an incidental pitfall I'd incur trying to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution packages `makemkv-libaacs` ([Arch example here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/makemkv-libaacs).) then you can install that and it will integrate with VLC player and a few others. Then in those player programs you go in the file menu and choose to open a disc. Select your Blu-ray drive and title number to play and it should just work from there.

Also, `makemkv-libaacs` is a decoding library. Despite the `makemkv` part of the title it does not RIP the entire file. It just decodes it as needed for an external player.

And you might want to [check out this site for an alternate method](http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name). Install the required files for your Linux distribution and use the given key database with VLC.

Finally, you certainly won’t be able to play a Blu-ray in a Windows VM as all legal software is required to support [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) which the VM will not be able to provide to the guest. Only the host, with a host licensed player, will be able to verify the HDCP path from computer to monitor.